# Lucene IndexSearcher#search(Query,int), impact of parameter n

Tags: java, performance, lucene

I have a Lucene index with ~ 9 Mio. documents, they are queried using a `BooleanQuery` which is combined of several `TermQueries` (which are combined as `AND`). Very basic. My searches usually yield in results of about 10 documents, but it might happen in rare cases, that I get considerably more results. What I'm doing, is something like the following:

```
TopDocs searchResult = searcher.search(query, MAX_RESULT_COUNT);
for (int i = 0; i < searchResult.scoreDocs.length; i++) {
    Document document = searcher.doc(searchResult.scoreDocs[i].doc);
    // read data from index fields and create result instances here
}
```

In my great naivety, I initially set `MAX_RESULT_COUNT` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, because I thought, if searches usually only get 10 results, the maximum value wouldn't matter and that value would never be reached anyways. Great mistake. As I discovered, search is magnitudes faster, the lower I set `MAX_RESULT_COUNT`.

Now, as mentioned, I could set a comparatively low value (e.g. 100) to obtain optimal search performance. But in some rare cases, there might be more results, which I also have to grab.

Can somebody explain to me, why this value has such a great impact on search speed, **although** the number of actually available results is magnitudes lower? Is there an elegant way to grab all available results and still get highest possible performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some quick skimming through the code, I found the following comment in [`PriorityQueue`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_1/core/org/apache/lucene/util/PriorityQueue.html)'s JavaDocs and assume that my problem was caused by the array allocation with a size of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`:

> NOTE: This class will pre-allocate a full array of length `maxSize+1` if instantiated via the `PriorityQueue(int,boolean)` constructor with prepopulate set to `true`.

I ended up writing a custom [`Collector`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Collector.html). As I do not need scoring and order of documents is irrelevant in my case, this was as simple as:

```
private static final class SimpleCollector extends Collector {
    final Set<Integer> docs = CollectionHelper.newHashSet();
    int docBase;

    @Override
    public void setScorer(Scorer scorer) throws IOException {
        // no scoring
    }

    @Override
    public void collect(int doc) throws IOException {
        docs.add(docBase + doc);
    }

    @Override
    public void setNextReader(AtomicReaderContext context) throws IOException {
        this.docBase = context.docBase;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean acceptsDocsOutOfOrder() {
        return true;
    }

}
```